# Play Doorbird audio stream with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Hy i tried to play a doorbird live audio stream via gstreamer gst-launch.
I found a code snipped in an fhem server script.

It should be possible with the command `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=<http://12.0.0.231/bha-api/audio-receive.cgi user=xxxx passwd=xxxx> ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! lame ! filesink location=a.mp3`

But i get following error: lame not found. if i change lame to lame lamemp3enc i get the error file not found http://12.0.0.231/bha-api/audio-receive.cgi

What do i wrong?